# Circular slider to continue counting after 360 degrees

Tags: swiftui, slider, circular-dependency

I aim to create a circular slider which you slide to increase a value - in the current code 60 secs for 360 degrees. Unfortunately it stops after 360 degrees or goes back to zero again. I am searching for a solution that I can slide several times and the value continues to increase. Any idea or hint very much appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView_orig: View {
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView{
            
            SetTimerView()
                .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
                .navigationTitle("SixTimes")
        }
    }
}


struct SetTimerView : View {
    
    @State var size = UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100
    @State var progress : CGFloat = 0
    @State var angle : Double = 0
    
    var body: some View{
        
        VStack{
            
            ZStack{
                
                Circle()
                    .stroke(Color("stroke"), style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 55, lineCap: .butt, lineJoin: .round))
                    .frame(width: size, height: size)

                // progress....
                Circle()
                    .trim(from: 0, to: progress)
                    .stroke(Color(hue: 0.352, saturation: 0.997, brightness: 1.0),style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 55, lineCap: .butt, lineJoin: .round))
                    .frame(width: size, height: size)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                
                // Static little circle at 0 degrees / starting position
                Circle()
//                    .fill(Color("stroke"))
                    .fill(Color.green)
                    .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
                    .offset(x: size / 2)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                
                // Drag Circle...
                Circle()
                    .fill(Color.white)
                    .frame(width: 55, height: 55)
                    .offset(x: size / 2)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: angle))
                // adding gesture...
                    .gesture(DragGesture().onChanged(onDrag(value:)))
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                
                // Here the time is shown in HH:MM:SS
                Text("Time (s): " + String(format: "%.0f", progress * 60))
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onDrag(value: DragGesture.Value){
        
        // calculating radians...
        
        let vector = CGVector(dx: value.location.x, dy: value.location.y)
        
        // since atan2 will give from -180 to 180...
        // eliminating drag gesture size
        // size = 55 => Radius = 27.5...
        let radians = atan2(vector.dy - 27.5, vector.dx - 27.5)

        
        // converting to angle...
        var angle = radians * 180 / .pi
        
        // simple technique for 0 to 360...
        // eg = 360 - 176 = 184...
        if angle < 0{angle = 360 + angle}
        
        // makes the sliding of the progress circle a bit smoother
        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.15)){
            
            
            // progress...
            let progress = angle / 360
            self.progress = progress
            self.angle = Double(angle)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_orig_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView_orig()
    }
}
```